# How do I write streamed output in NancyFX?

Tags: nancy

I'm writing a simple web application using Nancy. At least one request results in a stream of unknown length, so I can't provide `Content-Length`. I'd like to use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, or (equally acceptable in this case, `Connection: close`).

I've had a quick hack on the Nancy source code, and I've add `Response.BufferOutput`, and code to set `HttpContext.Response.BufferOutput` to `false`. You can see that here:

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule()
    {
        Get["/slow"] = _ => new SlowStreamResponse();
    }

    private class SlowStreamResponse : Response
    {
        public SlowStreamResponse()
        {
            ContentType = "text/plain";
            BufferOutput = false;
            Contents = s => {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                {
                    s.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect. The response turns up all at once, after 5 seconds. I've tested this a simple `WebRequest`-based client.

How do I get chunked output to work in Nancy? I'm using the ASP.NET hosting, but I'd be interested in answers for the other hosting options.

If I write a simple server using `HttpListener`, I can set `SendChunked` to `true`, and it sends chunked output, which my simple client correctly receives in chunks.

Comment: Where did you set the HttpContext.Response.BufferOutput in the Nancy code? And did you ever find a way to get this to work with OWIN?

Comment: I don't remember, sorry.

Comment: see the marked answer on this question => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953301/stream-an-sqlfile-stream-using-nancy

Answer (score 6):

During my experimentation, I discovered that I needed the following configuration.  First, set up your `web.config` file as documented in the [Nancy Wiki](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-asp.net).  It is worth noting that in order to set the `disableoutputbuffer` value (which is what we want), it appears that you currently need to also specify a bootstrapper.  Creating a class in your assembly that inherits from `Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.DefaultNancyAspNetBootstrapper` and specifying it in the configuration file appears to work.

```xml
<configSections>
  <section name="nancyFx" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyFxSection" />
</configSections>
<nancyFx>
  <bootstrapper assembly="YourAssembly" type="YourBootstrapper"/>
  <disableoutputbuffer value="true" />
</nancyFx>
```

Afterwards, you should not set the `Transfer-Encoding` header.  Rather, the following route definition appears to correctly stream the results from my IIS Express development server to Chrome:

```cs
Get["/chunked"] = _ =>
{
  var response = new Response();
  response.ContentType = "text/plain";
  response.Contents = s =>
  {
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
      for (var j = 0; j < 86; j++)
      {
        s.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
      }
      s.WriteByte(10);
      s.Flush();
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
  };

  return response;
};
```

I specified more content per chunk than the previous example due to the minimum sizes prior to first render documented in other [StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909227/using-transfer-encoding-chunked-how-much-data-must-be-sent-before-browsers-s)

Answer (score 4):

You have to call `Flush()` after each `Write()`, otherwise the response is buffered anyway. Moreover, Google Chrome doesn't render the output until it's all received.

I discovered this by writing a simple client application that logged what it was reading from the response stream as it arrived.

Comment: Not really. The 'BufferOutput' change isn't in core Nancy, and it only really works for the ASP.NET hosting. For WCF, you have to change the WebHttpBinding, I can't get self-hosting to work correctly, and I can't see any way to do it at all with the OWIN hosting.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe did you ever get anywhere with this? Im trying to get this working with NancyFx + ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

If using .NET 4.5+, you can alternatively use Stream.CopyTo instead of flush.

```
Get["/chunked"] = _ =>
{
  var response = new Response();
  response.ContentType = "text/plain";
  response.Contents = s =>
  {
    using(var helloStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World ")))
      helloStream.CopyTo(s);
  }
  return response;
}
```