# node.js express response.write() not async in Safari

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, safari

I have a very simple `node.js` server that I use to ping some servers I need to keep online.

Using [Express](http://expressjs.com) I have a very simple endpoint I can access that will perform a loop of requests and report the results.

Using `res.write()` on each loop, the webpage I load can show me the progress as it's happening.

The problem is, this progress doesn't happen in `Safari` on either `OS X` or `iOS`. It waits until the process is complete and then dumps the whole output in 1 go.

Here's an example of my code:

```
router.route('/test').get(function(req, res)
{
    res.write('<html><head></head><body>');
    res.write('Starting tests...<br />');
    performServerTests(req, res, function(results)
    { // Each loop within performServerTests also uses res.write()
        res.write('<br />Complete');
        res.end('</body></html>');
    });
});
```

Is there a known reason why Safari would wait for the `res.end()` call before displaying what it already has, while Chrome shows each `res.write()` message as it receives it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using chunked transfers (what you're trying to do), browsers are generally waiting for a minimum amount of data to be received before starting rendering. The exact size is browser-specific - see [Using "transfer-encoding: chunked", how much data must be sent before browsers start rendering it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909227/using-transfer-encoding-chunked-how-much-data-must-be-sent-before-browsers-s) for some quite recent data points on this.
You example could for example be written like this (adding some headers to be explicit too):

```
router.route('/test').get(function(req, res)
{
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
    res.write('<html><head></head><body>');
    res.write('Starting tests...<br />');
    var buf = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        buf += " "
    }
    res.write(buf);
    performServerTests(req, res, function(results)
    { // Each loop within performServerTests also uses res.write()
        res.write('<br />Complete');
        res.end('</body></html>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Guitan. You where spot on. Safari just needed a bit more data before it started displaying.