# Safari doesn't render until all scripts are ready not like Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, safari, render

http://stevesouders.com/tests/ix-js.php

This page has 8000ms script before `</body>`. As I know, browsers render progressively, so it doesn't affect the visual result. Chrome and Firefox perform as I expected. But, Safari - both in macOS and iOS - doesn't.

It WAITS until the script is downloaded and parsed.
Very weird.

http://stevesouders.com/hpws/move-scripts.php

Here's another example. For this, Safari renders normally, as I expected.

Please explain this confusing behavior. I tried but even `defer` or `async` are not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the size of the content matters. The content of the first link is too small to render on Safari.

Please refer this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16909228/2480917