# Is there any workaround to send response until a promise is finished and send another response after it is finished in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, promise, es6-promise

I have a promise call which takes a long time to return. So I need to send some response  like "In progress" until the response is returned. Once it is returned , I need to send another response saying "Done".

I want this in Nodejs-Express App

How to do it?

Comment: You can only respond once to a given request. Typically you'd return "accepted" and give a location to poll for updates.

Comment: While [technically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16909228/1048572) [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1806228/1048572), it's rather unusual. You'd use something like [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using SocketIO would be an option  as you would maintain a stream of data open while it is required. But you go beyond of a simple http Express server ...