# Streaming large results from a GET call

Tags: nancy

I'm trying to return a large dataset from a GET operation and would like to stream this to the user, so they can work with the initial part of the dataset while more is sent to the user.

The closest issue I've seen to this is [How do I write streamed output in NancyFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484873/how-do-i-write-streamed-output-in-nancyfx), but there was no solution in this issue and I've found very little online for the problem I'm trying to solve.

Anyone have any ideas or articles that may be of use for this issue?