# Does Chunked Transfer Encoding work with Nancy, OWIN and HttpListener?

Tags: .net, owin, nancy

I am using Nancy, OWIN and Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener to self host REST service.

One of my services needs to return a lot of data and I want to stream it to the client.

This doesn't work:

```
Get["/stream"] = _ =>
{
    var response = new Response();
    response.Headers.Add("Transfer-Encoding", "Chunked");
    response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    response.Contents = s =>
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            s.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            s.Flush();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    };

    return response;
};
```

Should this work and if so what am I doing wrong? Looking at the results in Fiddler, Content-Length is set and the entire response is only seen after 20 seconds.

(I can't find any conclusive answers on Google. 
[How do I write streamed output in NancyFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484873/how-do-i-write-streamed-output-in-nancyfx) - this questions seems to imply it doesn't work but I wonder if it has been fixed as this was asked a while ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, this does work correctly *but* it doesn't work with Fiddler. Fiddler captures the entire response in one go.